# When using zsh tab-completion, Ignore CDPATH if a local file or directory matches

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I love Z shell's tab completion with CDPATH, but sometimes it's overkill.  I'd like it to only kick in as a fall-back if nothing in the local directory matches.

For instance, I was just in `~/Code/Haxe` and typed

```
$ cd h<tab>
```

knowing that the only directory there beginning with an `h` was `haxe.org`.  Instead of completing the directory name I got a bunch of things beginning with `h` from my CDPATH.  On the other hand, I wouldn't want to live without it, since (along with AUTO_CD) I can get to that directory (or countless others) simply by typing `Haxe`.  I use this *all the time*, but I'd like to make it take a backseat to switching to local directories.

I've not found any questions that deal with this problem.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680048/zstyle-separate-cdpath-completions-from-locals) deals with the display of suggested completions, but that's not what I care about.  I want to simply ignore everything from CDPATH when a local directory matches perfectly.

Comment: Is the first char `:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any zstyle setting for that. What you can do is try completion with an empty `cdpath`, and if that fails, try with `cdpath`.

```
_cd_try_without_cdpath () {
  CDPATH= _cd "$@" || _cd "$@"
}
compdef _cd_try_without_cdpath cd pushd
```

Comment: `zstyle ':completion:*:complete:(cd|pushd):*' tag-order 'local-directories named-directories'` seems to be a cleaner way to acheive this. It excludes `path-directories` from the tags that will be generated, but they'll still be used as a fallback if no other results are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because my console switched to a folder in `~` (which is in my `CDPATH`) instead of a subfolder of where I currently was. I'm not sure if this is exactly what this question is about, but my solution was to simply append `.:` at the start of `CDPATH`. So then the entry in `.bashrc` looked like this:

```
CDPATH=".:/home/fabian:$drive"
```

That way `cd` always prefers whatever is in the current folder, but can still switch to the others if there's nothing in the current one.

(Also, I was using Bash instead of ZSH, but it's likely the same or similar for both.)

Note: This breaks "`cd`" (without arguments) as a shortcut for "`cd ~`".